# Using net.ipv4.ip_forward=0 for LXC containers causes DUP! ICMP packets on VMs

Tags: virtualization, lxc, icmp

I run LXC Linux containers and so I have net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 set on the host so that I can ping internet (google.com) from inside the LXC container.

However, when I run VirtualBox VMs in the same environment and bridge to the wlan wireless interface I get duplicate ICMP packets (DUP!). I can stop the duplicate packets in the VirtualBox VM by setting net.ipv4.ip_forward=0 on the host, but then this breaks the resolution of internet in the LXC containers.

How can I prevent the DUP! pings in the VM and leave net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 set? Thanks.